# closing a snackbar on clicking a button other than action button of it in android

Tags: android, snackbar

**I display a snackbar using the code**

```
Snackbar.make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Action", null)
                .show();
```

This snackbar is kept displayed on screen

**What I am trying to do**:

- Once it is kept displayed on screen, How to dismiss it when i click
  on a view which is different from snackbar action button
- Is it possible

Comment: Did you try using `dismiss` method on the snackbar object? Of course first save the reference to the snackbar rather than call `show` on it immediately.

Comment: try keeping a reference to your snackbar by assigning it to a local variable and call dismiss from that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Action", null);
mySnackbar.show();
```

After this just do (in other view's `onClickListener`):

```
mySnackbar.dismiss();
```

Comment: damn, was just about to post the answer :)

Comment: Seems like a few of us were. I first typed the comment and then the answer :D

Comment: brain lag :( i dont think the code posted by OP will actually make a valid snackbar though, double .make statement

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by keeping a reference to that snackbar instance:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Action", null)
                .show();
```

Now whenever you want to dismiss it just call `.dismiss()`, so in your case:

```
theOtherButton.setOnClickListener { snackbar.dismiss() }
```

Comment: val is kotlin, not java :)

Comment: So? Where does the question show if it is Java or Kotlin? ^^

Comment: it has a semicolon at ````.show();```` haha but i don't blame you, i've been doing kotlin for so long now that answering stuff in java is almost impossible :)

Comment: ';' are allowed in Kotlin hehe. But this -> https://techcrunch.com/2019/05/07/kotlin-is-now-googles-preferred-language-for-android-app-development/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer_us=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_cs=Oi1dYknjQto4xZVtYYztZA motivates me to post in Kotlin (also I don't use Java in my day to day work hehe)

Comment: i agree that the semicolons are allowed in kotlin, but most people learn to remove them, also, OP has posted various other questions in java, but really we are just arguing for nothing at this point :) i do agree with your answer either way though :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Use
yourSnackbar.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

> You can surround with InkWell as:

```
SnackBar(
  content: InkWell(
    onTap: () {ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();},
```